# yaw angle reading probemc#

Tags: c#, mavlink

I have a little problem with my yaw angle. I am developing an application that calibrates my magneto. But when I'm reading my angles from the at-sensor, I have something very weird for the yaw angle. Normally I should have something stable, but I get the following results:

The yaw varies a lot if I keep going my program it will go until negative values. The problem is just for the yaw angle.

[image]

Comment: Then edit your question and put it in there. Also, are those the raw values? Are you doing some sort of filtering?

Comment: yes they are raw values, and no they are not yet filtred.